# Asginar eventos a multiples a varios botones

Tags: php, jquery

Estoy creando un grid que permita seleccionar x cantidad de botones con numeros, y cuando el usuario le de click al boton muestre el numero que este representa, muestro el codigo.

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{
 $('#item1').click(()=>{//Quisiera implementar esto en cada uno de los 
                         //botones, solo este funciona.
  $('#item1').toggleClass('active')
  $('#item1').toggleClass('disabled') 
 })
$('.item').click(()=>{
 $(this).toggleClass('active')
    $(this).toggleClass('disabled') //Los toggleClass tampoco se ejecutan al darle click 
 let valor= $(this).attr('value')
 console.log(valor) //retorna undefined
 
})


});
```

```html
<?php 
echo "
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
 <meta charset='UTF-8'>
 <title>Testing</title>
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/main.css'>
 <!-- <script src='js/jquery.plugin.min.js'></script>  -->
 <script src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
 <script src='js/main.js'></script>
  <script         src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">   </script>  
</head>
<body>


 <div id='grid'>
  <table>
   ";
   echo "<tr>";
    for ($i=1; $i <=500; $i++) { 
    echo "
    <td class='item active' id='item".$i."'>".str_pad($i, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)."</td> 
    ";
    if ($i%10==0 || $i==0)  {
   echo "</tr><tr>";
   }
  }
  echo " 
 </table>  
</div>

</body>
</html>

";

?>
```

Sucede que tengo que agregar esta funcion a cada uno de los botones, pero no me parece una solucion correcta, crear un codigo para cada boton.
Soy nuevo programando y es una de mis primera tareas como programador, alguna idea de como puedo resolver esto?

Answer (score 1):

Espero lo siguiente sirva:

```
  $(document).ready(()=>{
        $('.clase_boton').click(()=>{
          //a cada botnton con la clase "clase_boton" se el asigan el evento click, y lo que esté aquí a dentro se va a hacer solo para el botón al cual usted le dio click
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            $(this).toggleClass('disabled');
            let numero_boton=$(this).attr('value'); //así saca el número del botón que debe estar en el atributo "value del botón"
        })


    });
```

Comment: Excelente idea, sin embargo si hago un console.log de numero_boton, me muestra "undefined"

Comment: Porque seguramente su botón no tiene el atributo "value"

Comment: De hecho si, lo hice tal como indicaste y le agregue el atributo value a cada item, e igual retorna undefined, de igual manera si pido el atributo id ($(this).attr('id')) tambien me retorna undefined...

Comment: el html debería está de esta forma `<td><button class="clase_boton" value="21">botón</button></td>`

Comment: Lo acabo de actualizar a como lo tengo... Como te dije me retorna undefined, no tengo idea de que la razon... Tambien retorna indefined si $(this).attr('id')